# Как избавиться от ошибки `system.data.sqlserverce.4.0 could not be loaded`

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

У меня есть  проблема. Уже полдня борюсь с ошибкой, а она все есть
[image: Код ошибки]

Я уже все перерыл, но не вижу, что не так. 
Походу, оно на эту строку кричит:

```
  public DataBaseContext() : base("DbConnection")
```

В этом класcе:

```
 public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DataBaseContext() : base("DbConnection")
    { }

    public DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

AppConfig:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source= .\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SocialNetwork;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info = True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Помогите увидеть ошибку...

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перевел ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456378/ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name-system-data-sqlserverce-4-0-could-not-be)

У Вас установлен `Sql Compact`, но отсутствует `EntityFramework extension for Sql Compact`. Установите это пакет через консоль менеджера пакетов или через nuget.

Консольный скрипт:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact
```